# how to intercept an SMS in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

Good morning, I have the following code:

```
int numero = 22492;
String  PhnNoStr = String.valueOf (numero);
String transaction = WriteText(tipoTransacao);
String SmsStr = "ECART" + "" + transaction + idToken;
System.out.println ("Message:" + smsStr);
MessageConnection msgCon = null;
msgCon = (MessageConnection) Connector.open ("sms :/ /" + + phnNoStr ": 500");
TextMessage TxtMsg = (TextMessage) msgCon.newMessage (MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
txtMsg.setPayloadText (smsStr);
msgCon.send (TxtMsg);
```

so I send that message by default it returns me a message. I can send and receive this message, however I need to intercept when I receive this message, does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *intercept*?

Comment: when I send the message it returns me an outstanding balance, which I
need it, when return the message I need to get information
within this message and display it in my own application.

Comment: unless it sends to a port number you can't do it

Comment: Sorry, did not understand ... can you explain again? .. researched and read that could use PushRegistry but do not know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use PushRegistry to have your midlet launched when a SMS is received and midlet is not running.

```
PushRegistry.registerConnection("sms://:500", "your_package.Your_MIDlet", "*");
```

To handle incoming SMS, you need to open connection and listen for incoming message, eg:

```
class SMSHandler implements MessageListener, Runnable {
    public void start() {
        ...
        connection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://:500", Connector.READ);
        connection.setMessageListener(this);
    }

    public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection messageConnection) {
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        final Message message = connection.receive();
        ...
    }
```

(The reason for processing the message in another thread is that blocking I/O should not be done in system callback - at least WTK emulator will print warning, and on some phones midlet will just freeze).